# update one common CELL and reflect the same in range of other columns

Tags: excel

HI I have 3 columns and multiple rows in a excel

```
date time event 
10/11 4:50pm sucess
10/11 4:50pm sucess
10/11 4:20pm sucess
10/11 4:20pm sucess
10/11 4:53pm sucess
10/11 4:53pm sucess
```

I want to have a common CELL  which will be used to update column (DATE) RANGE 1-3 in date column .

so if I update that one CELL as NULL my data in date column RANGE 1-3 gets automatically updated s null .

```
date time event 
NULL 4:50pm sucess
NULL  4:50pm sucess
NULL  4:20pm sucess
10/11 4:20pm sucess
10/11 4:53pm sucess
10/11 4:53pm sucess
```

Comment: You should show what effort you've put into solving this issue yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your formatted date in cell **E1** and in **A2** through **A4** enter:

```
=$E$1
```

[image]

Then all we need to do is change **E1** to *Null* to achieve:

[image]